# multiple count(0 on table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a vehicle database and want  to count how many cars have a specific colour.

But I don't know what colours there are as there are many, also combinations. 
So this code does not do the trick for me:

```
    SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN colour='red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) red,
        SUM(CASE WHEN colour='green' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) green
    (etc)
    FROM vehicles
```

To get all colours, I could do:

```
    select distinct colour from vehicles
```

But how can I use that information in a sql statement like the one above?
I am using MS sql server.

Comment: What you're after is a `GROUP BY` clause. [SELECT - GROUP BY- Transact-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: and instead of colours I should be able to count makes/models as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put the result set in rows rather than columns:

```
SELECT colour, count(*)
FROM vehicles
GROUP BY colour;
```

The alternative is that you would need to use dynamic SQL or express the result set as XML or JSON.

Comment: @Larnu After reading the through the group-by page , I came to exactly the same solution. Precisely what I needed! I never understood GROUP-BY properly, so thanks for that

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply do the aggregation ?

```
select colour, count(*) as no_vehicles
from vehicles v
group by colour;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will pull a list of all colours found in table vehicles:

```
SELECT distinct colour
 from vehicles
```

But what you really want to use is the [group by](https://www.dofactory.com/sql/group-by) clause, like so:

```
SELECT
  colours
 ,count(*)  HowMany
 from vehicles
 group by
  colours
```

This will produce one row for every distinct value in column `colours`. It will NOT parse out color combinations; "red with black trim" will be its own column, and not +1 for red, _1 for black--that would be a much more complex problem.